# pandas: Calculate new values in the new column from multiple criteria apply from multiple columns without looping

Tags: python, pandas

I have my data in the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AccID':['001','001','001','002','002','003'],
                   'AccTypes':['A','B','C','A','B','C'],
                   'Status':['Closed','Active','Active','Active','Closed','Active'],
                   'Years':[5,15,10,20,25,30]})

AccID     AccTypes     Status     Years
001       A            Closed     5
001       B            Active     15
001       C            Active     10
002       A            Active     20
002       B            Closed     25
003       C            Active     30
```

I would like to create another column called 'ActiveYears' which each value is the **maximum active years** for a given **active AccID regardless AccTypes**.  The expected output is in the following:

```
AccID     AccTypes     Status     Years     ActiveYears     Explanations
001       A            Closed     5         5               # Status = Closed, we set ActiveYears = Years
001       B            Active     15        15              # Status = Active, we select the maximum year of AccID = 001 with active status
001       C            Active     10        15              # Status = Active, we select the maximum year of AccID = 001 with active status
002       A            Active     20        20              # Status = Active, we select the maximum year of AccID = 002 with active status
002       B            Closed     25        20              # Status = Closed, we set ActiveYears = Years
003       C            Active     30        30              # Status = Active, we select the maximum year of AccID = 003 with active status
```

I can do this with looping but it is not elegant enough.  May I know how to do this in the better way than looping?  Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `(002,B)` have `(Years, ActiveYears) = (25, 25)` since it's closed? Years is 25, so ActiveYears = Years  25, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

Deal with the Status `Closed` first:

```
df.loc[df.Status == 'Closed','ActiveYears'] = df.loc[df.Status == 'Closed','Years']
```

Deal with active, using a [groupby transformation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df.loc[df.Status == 'Active', 'ActiveYears'] = df[df.Status == 'Active'].groupby('AccID')['Years'].transform(max)

print(df)

  AccID AccTypes  Status  Years  ActiveYears
0   001        A  Closed      5          5.0
1   001        B  Active     15         15.0
2   001        C  Active     10         15.0
3   002        A  Active     20         20.0
4   002        B  Closed     25         25.0
5   003        C  Active     30         30.0
```